# How to have a fish riding on an invisible squid in 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friends and I are trying to make realistic aquariums in 1.9 using commands with no mods or plugins to do this for us. How could I spawn different kinds on fish on invisible squids? Thanks! 
I have already tried `/summon Item ~ ~+1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:fish},Count:1,{Riding:{id:"Squid"}}`

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We might be able to find a solution faster if we know what you've already attempted.

Comment: Minecraft-speaking, what's a fish?

Comment: @MrLemon probably an item

Comment: its an item you get when catching. I thought i wouldn't need to specify that in my question

Comment: @DatOneLefty uhh... good point. I was focussing on entities, I forgot about items together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Riding` compound tag has been removed in 1.9. The `Passengers` list tag takes its place, except the stack order is reversed (in that the host entity is the one in the `/summon` syntax, rather than the one at the lowest depth of `Riding`).

The `Count` tag must also be placed inside the `Item` compound.

```
/summon Squid ~ ~+1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:minecraft:fish,Count:1}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this has already been answered, I would like to extend Skylinerw's answer.

```
/summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:minecraft:fish,Count:1,Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767}}]}
```

What "Age" is the despawn time of the item. By putting -32768, we do not allow it to despawn.

What "PickupDelay" is the delay of picking up the dropped item. A simple proof of concept is to drop an item below your feet. There would be a short delay before you pick it up. By putting 32767, we do not allow it to be picked up.